# How can I display my database dates php

Tags: php, sql

How can display my database dates when I am getting rows from select query? Here is my code:

```
   mysql_connect(db_server, db_user, db_pass);
   $result = mysql_db_query(db_name,"SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY user_id DESC LIMIT 5");
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
       echo "<td>" . $row['sign_up_stamp'] . "</td>"; 
   }

   database outputs 2147483647
```

How can I display my the actual date instead of the database enumeration?

Comment: The answer depends on whether you want the date to be human readable in the database or if you just want the end result to be human readable. Depending on your needs, storing a timestamp like you are is perfectly acceptable and then converting it on the fly for displaying to a user. If you need to be able to process dates within your database then a different data type for that field may be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo date('m/d/Y', 2147483647);`

or for user variable specific:

`echo date('m/d/Y', $row['sign_up_stamp']);`

Answer (score 1):

this mistake because of wrong field type in your database design.
put your field type to `datetime` or if you like to use time stamp you must format it with date functions in php